# MySQL:How to make a trigger that rejects underage employees?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, triggers, sql-insert

I want to create a trigger that rejects the insert of an underage employee, by underage I mean that his year of birth is 2004 or more.
I wrote the following code, it runs without errors but then it doesn't let me insert any employee because it says :
ERROR: Unknown column 'BIRTHDATE' IN 'field list'

When I drop the trigger everything works fine.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER REJECT_EMP
BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF YEAR(BIRTHDATE) > 2003 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You could build this logic (minus the returned error message) into the INSERT itself. Note that your trigger is valid only for one year.

Comment: (1) Why would you be checking only the year of birth and not the date?  (2) You trigger will reject different ages as time goes by.  Your question should explain the full logic of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should be testing NEW.BIRTHDATE

'Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, I would recommend a check constraint rather than trigger logic.

```
alter table employee
    add constraint chk_birthdate
    check(year(birthdate) > 2003)
;
```

This enforces the same check that the trigger does, but the syntax is much shorter, and the logic is bundled directly in the definition of the table (so it is somehow easier to maintain). When an attempt is made to insert an offending row, you get the following error message:

```
Check constraint 'chk_birthdate' is violated.
```

Comment: This is nice solution, but demand to alter table each year

Answer (score 0):

I have to advice 2 changes in your trigger:

- fist as @P.Salmon answered you should to use `NEW.BIRTHDATE` parameter
- second use age instead birth-year in comparison

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER REJECT_EMP
    BEFORE INSERT ON EMPLOYEE
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, NEW.BIRTHDATE, NOW()) < 17 THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
        END IF;
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the right way to check `year()` is on a day-by-day basis.  So the logic that you want is:

```
BEGIN
    IF BIRTHDATE > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 16 YEAR THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
    END IF;
END$$
```

This actually checks the *date of birth*.  So someone can become an employee on their birthday.

I am not sure "16" is the right value, but your question doesn't explain it.  It makes sense given the logic you have presented and that the year when you asked the question is 2020.